# python loops does not break even after successful while statement

Tags: python

My while loop does not break even after successful while recall. I need to check if the number exists and if it doesnt my while loop should break and successfull print out the number apart from 1 / 3 or 6

```
def is_1(inp):
if inp == 1:
    print("1 it is")
    return False

def is_3(inp):
    if inp == 3:
        print("3 it is")
        return False
    
def is_6(inp):
    if inp == 6:
        print("6 it is")
        return False
    
# ------------------------
me = False
while me != True:
    try:
        inpp = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
        if any([is_1(inpp),is_3(inpp),is_6(inpp)]) == False:
            me = False
        else:
            me = True
            print(inpp)
    except IndexError:
        print('Inappropriate domain and username')
```

[image]

Comment: It might be worth thinking about the logic a bit. You are returning `False` if the condition **is** met which is very confusing and which might be the reason why you're running into problems.

Comment: Just try switching the `False` with `True` value and vice versa.

Comment: There is no way for ``is_1`` etc to return anything but ``False`` or ``None``, *both of which are false'y*. There is no way for ``any([is_1(inpp),is_3(inpp),is_6(inpp)])`` to ever be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the functions `is_1()`, `is_3()`, `is_6()` returns `None` when the respective condition is **not** met.

This means, if you enter any number **other than** 1, 3, or 6, this will lead to an array containing only `None`s in the line

```python
if any([is_1(inpp),is_3(inpp),is_6(inpp)]) == False:
```

i.e.

```python
if any([None,None,None]) == False:
```

This, in turn, will evaluates to `False`.

In other words, the line `me = True` is never reached.

In order to fix this, you need to make the three methods above return something that evaluates to `True` if the condition **isn't** met (i.e. when you are passing in anything else than 1,3, or 6).

Answer (score 0):

You just add a break and rewrite you if statements. That would break your loop. (Also according to what @p3j4p5 wrote)

Here is the code:

```py
def is_1(inp):
    if inp == 1:
        print("1 it is")
        return False

def is_3(inp):
    if inp == 3:
        print("3 it is")
        return False
    
def is_6(inp):
    if inp == 6:
        print("6 it is")
        return False
    
# ------------------------
me = False
while me != True:
    try:
        inpp = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
        if inpp not in (1, 3, 6):
            me = True
            print(inpp)
            break
        elif any([is_1(inpp),is_3(inpp),is_6(inpp)]) == False:
            me = False
    except IndexError:
        print('Inappropriate domain and username')
```

Now if the input is not in 1 or 3 or 6 it will break. Is this the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem `is_1`, `is_3`, and `is_6` will evaluate to `none` if `inp != 1`, and because of the code also to `false` if `inp ==1`

```
def is_1(inp):
    if inp == 1:
        print("1 it is")
        return False
```

2-

`any([item1, item2, ....])` returns `true` if any (or at least one) of the items is `true`. Otherwise It returns `false`

And because `is_1` and `is_3` and `is_6` always return `false` or `none`, `any([is_1(inpp),is_3(inpp),is_6(inpp)])` will always be false and `me` will always be `false`.

To fix the issue, `is_1` and `is_3` and `is_6` needs to return a true value:

```
def is_1(inp):
    if inp == 1:
        print("1 it is")
        return True

def is_3(inp):1
    if inp == 3:
        print("3 it is")
        return True
    
def is_6(inp):
    if inp == 6:
        print("6 it is")
        return True
    
# ------------------------
me = False
while me != True:
    try:
        inpp = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
        if any([is_1(inpp),is_3(inpp),is_6(inpp)]) == False:
            me = False
        else:
            me = True
            print(inpp)
    except IndexError:
        print('Inappropriate domain and username')
```